# Why does python print([False, True][True]) output True

Tags: python

Is this some kind of ternary operation?

```
print([False, True][True])
```

Why is the output True?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the `True` is interpreted as the index location `1`.

Try `[1, 2, 3][True]` and you will get `2`.

Answer (score 2):

In this case Python translates True to 1 (and False to 0). Index 1 means that you are accessing the second element in the array which in this case is true.

So if you try `print([True, False][True])` it will output False, `print([True, False][False])` will output True, ...

Answer (score 0):

The numeric representation of `True` is `1` (`0` for `False`)

You can try `print(int(True))`, it will output `1`

`print([False, True][True])` will then be quivalent to `print([False, True][1])`, and then, display `True`